# Where to put the placeholder in wpdb-prepare

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I know this has been asked before, but in my case, i'm kinda stumped where i need to put my placeholders:

```
$prepared = $wpdb->prepare(
"
    SELECT *
    FROM tarieven
    WHERE bestemming 
    = '" . trim($_POST['destination']) . "'
",
'value', 'another value'
);

$results = $wpdb->get_results($prepared);
```

Comment: Where your putting values, bestemning = ___

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Took my sweet time, but i understand it now, had to replace my var with the placeholder.

```
$prepared = $wpdb->prepare(
"
    SELECT *
    FROM tarieven
    WHERE bestemming 
    = %s
",
trim($_POST['destination'])
);

$results = $wpdb->get_results($prepared);
```